# How to create ConditionExpression for QueryExpression on statecode in early bound?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, query-expressions

In late bound I'd use something like this to add a condition for only getting active records.

```csharp
new ConditionExpression
{
  AttributeName = "statecode",
  Operator = ConditionOperator.NotEqual,
  Values = { SomeClass.Active }
}
```

But how do I express that in late bound?

Also, why does [MS demand to cast it to *String*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334419.aspx) instead of *int*?

> When you create a condition that compares an attribute value to an enumeration, such as a state code, you must use the ToString method to convert the value to a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like

```
ConditionExpression condition1 = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ConditionExpression
{
    AttributeName = "statecode",
    Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
    Values = { "Active" } //or SomeEnum.Active.ToString() if you want use good practice
};
```

should work fine.

Edit:
other option is to cast enums to int: `Values = {(int)SomeEnum.Active}`

Comment: I don't get why. If we use the string "Active", we shouldn't get the same behavior as if we use an enum (which is an *int*). Also, your use of the enum makes me suspect that you're talking early bound. Is it so?

Comment: Me neither :) Must be some issue when casting enums in SDK code. I have mentioned enum, just to point out that you can create your own enum to avoid hardcoding strings or ints.

Comment: conditions on statecode and statuscode accept both int and string, don't ask me why but works